# Which would be more efficient for an email server : mysql or .json file?

Tags: php, email

I am making an email server so huge amount of emails will be sent and received every minute. I am worried that if I use mysql then here will be too much load and the database will crash. Is it advisable to use .json / .txt file for storing emails?

Comment: Too broad. So many options here. Please run some regression testing mixed with load balancing and sort this out yourself. If you encounter issues during that process, do check SO for your answers. If none are found, feel free to ask a question with `valid code included`.

Comment: If you want to consider using a json/text file, then consider potential locking/conflict issues with that much activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guarantee that the MySQLs DBM will handle file access and reading/writing to disk more efficiently, and utilize caching better than to simply use the file system. MySql is quite durable and should handle it (though you have not specified the actual load so its very hard to say).